# custom combobox win32

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox, subclass, autosuggest

I am trying to implement an auto-suggest feature in an win32 combobox (C++). I want to achieve a behaviour that is similar to the google auto suggest function. When the user types something into the edit-control of the combobox, its listbox opens and shows all possible matches. The Problem is the default behaviour of a win32 combobox is to always select the closest match and put the complete text (selected) into the edit control when the list is opened. I need to avoid this behaviour. The list should just open - dont select something and dont change the text in the edit-control! 
I have tried to subclass the combobox and catch the CBN_DROPDOWN message, but this changes nothing on the default behavior.

Does anyone have a further idea? I dont want the auto-complete feature that just completes the text in the edit-control without opening the list.

Thx in advance
Greets, Michael

Comment: You can use the AutoComplete object in AutoSuggest mode. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes thx, that should work. But its quite hard to implement for custom auto-complete sources - I have a list of strings to be used rather than the predefined files/urls. Has anybody sample code for that?

Comment: You just need to hand it an IEnumString that spits out the strings you want to use. ATL has a pre-made enumerator you can use.

Comment: In fact autocomplete source would be easier to implement, provided that all UI functionality and integration with edit control, including things like suggestions as you type, are already available for you. With combo box you will only be able to populate the list, and further customization will require additional effort be put in.

Comment: Thx Roman, I dont completely understand your comment - do you mean I should only use an edit control rather than the combobox? Does anyone have source code sample for that?

Comment: Does IAutoComplete only work for edit-controls of ComboBoxEx or with the normal ComboBox as well?