# IAutoComplete custom source with IEnumString

Tags: c++, winapi, autocomplete

I am trying to implement auto-suggest for a comboxbox (win32, c++) or an edit-control. But I dont know how to use the interface IAutoComplete correctly. I need a custom list of strings where the matches for auto-suggest should be taken from. But how to implement this with IEnumString? I found this link but it doesnt reveal everything: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Has anybody ever implemented this?
Thx in advance
Michael

Comment: This is perhaps a continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728103/custom-combobox-win32

Comment: Yes it is. I dont understand how it can be implemented, so I need sample code.

Comment: IAutoComplete and custom IEnumString implementation for WTL dialogs http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/customautocomplete_wtl.aspx

Answer (score 6):

As I noted in my comment, ATL has one pre-written for you.

```
typedef CComEnum<IEnumString,
                 &IID_IEnumString,
                 LPOLESTR,
                 _Copy<LPOLESTR> > CComEnumString;

CComObject<CComEnumString> *pes;
HRESULT hr = CComObject<CComEnumString>::CreateInstance(&pes);
```

That code was basically stolen from [the CComEnum documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cse81cwk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: It helps very much, thx! But how can I initialize the array with strings via pes->Init(... ?

Comment: I'll let you figure that out.

Comment: @Michbeckable Hi, Did you manage to get it to work?  I really lost in this COM kinda stuffs. Essentially I want the same I have CEdit and the array. I would like to have suggestions from that array in some dropdown list. Can you share your code with me?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with the help of all answers I got it so far:

```
            IAutoComplete *pac;

        HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AutoComplete, 
                                        NULL, 
                                      CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                                      IID_PPV_ARGS(&pac));

        typedef CComEnum<IEnumString,
             &IID_IEnumString,
             LPOLESTR,
             _Copy<LPOLESTR> > CComEnumString;

        CComObject<CComEnumString> *pes;
        HRESULT hRes = CComObject<CComEnumString>::CreateInstance(&pes);

        // hRes = pes->Init(

        IUnknown* pUnk;
        hRes = pes->QueryInterface(IID_IEnumString, (void**) &pUnk);

        pac->Init(hEdit, pUnk, NULL, NULL);

        // maybe we release ?
        pUnk->Release();

        IAutoComplete2 *pac2;

        if (SUCCEEDED(pac->QueryInterface(IID_IAutoComplete2, (LPVOID*)&pac2)))
        {
            pac2->SetOptions(ACO_AUTOSUGGEST);
            pac2->Release();
        }
```

There is just one thing remaining:

The initialisation of the CComObject *pes. Lets assume I have an array like this:

```
std::string myArray[] = { string("abc"), string("foo"), string("muh") };
```

Now I want these strings to be stuffed into the pes->Init(...) method. How is the conversion to LPOLESTR actually done here? The Init(...) method taes a pointer to the begin and end of this array. The end should be one position BEYOND the last array element, so would this be myArray[3] here? I am just asking because I think this is actually out of bounds in this array?

Thx very much!